# OpenAI Gym/Gymnasium Custom Env: How should done signal be defined in a continuous task/infinite horizon problem?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am creating a custom gym environment that should abstract a non-episodic/continuous task.

Generally `gym` requires to return `obs, reward, done, info` after each step:

```py
obs, reward, done, info = env.step(actions)
```

Now, what if there will never be a termination signal (`done`)?
Should my implementation always return `done = False` or should it always return `done = True`?
Would returning one or the other make a difference for the RL-algorithms that are using it (particularly looking at stable-baselines here)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference. If your `done` flag was always True, then you would always have episodes of length one, which is the opposite of what you want.

What the updated version of Gym, Gymnasium, has introduced, is a `terminated` and `truncated` flag. Rather than receive a single `done` flag we are now told whether the termination was a true termination, i.e. we have reached a terminal state, or whether the episode is being truncated. This is useful for continuing tasks like you mentioned because you can reset the environment, which is typically good for exploration, but still bootstrap from your next state.